# How do I create a spark application written in Java that reads 2 files for processing

Tags: java, apache-spark

A team is working with data that has already been conformed and I have to take that data and make it ready for semantics.

There are 2 files:
1st file has 3 fields:
1)Product ID
2)Product Name
3)Product Category

2nd File has 3 fields as well:
1)Product ID
2)Order ID
3)Order Amount

I have to write a spark application that reads data from both files and find out what are the LEAST sold products by product category. MUST BE IN JAVA

How will I be able to go about this?

Please and thank you.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: 1. learn java,  2. learn string processing,  3. learn spark, 
 4.write the app. i am not sure about the ordering of these steps but they should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two dataframes by reading both the files in spark.
2. Apply logic over these dataframes by using dataframes methods or spark sql query.
3. then save the output at target location.

please go through below link of spark API documentation to get the exact syntax and details.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html